# A generic signature for self referencing entity?

Tags: java, generics, self-reference

I defined an interface for a child entities of a specified type.

```java
// a child of T
interface IChildEntity<T> {
    T getParent();
}
```

Now I'm trying to define an interface for self-referencing entities.

Which one of these definitions is preferred?

```java
interface ISelfReferencingEntity<T extends ISelfReferencingEntity<T>>
        extends IChildEntity<T> {
}
```

```java
interface ISelfReferencingEntity<T extends ISelfReferencingEntity<T> & IChildEntity<T>>
        extends IChildEntity<T> {
}
```

Here comes an actual entity class applicable.

```java
class Category implements ISelfReferencingEntity<Category> {

    @ManyToOne
    private Category parent;
}
```

The original concern is whether adding `& IChildEntity<T>` part along with `extends IChildEntity<T>` is redundant or not.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? When you say self-referencing are you referring to an object of the same type or potentially the same reference of the given type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T extends ISelfReferencingEntity<T>` implies `T extends IChildEntity<T>` since `ISelfReferencingEntity<T>` is a subtype of `IChildEntity<T>`. Therefore, adding `& IChildEntity<T>` to `T extends ISelfReferencingEntity<T>` is redundant.

The following definition is preferred:

```
interface ISelfReferencingEntity<T extends ISelfReferencingEntity<T>>
        extends IChildEntity<T> {
}
```